# Fail to download KEGG data... (R language, enrichKEGG() function)

Tags: r

I run the [KEGG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KEGG) enrichment in R (version 4.0.3) using the function `enrichKEGG()`, but it returns the message of

> fail to download KEGG data...
> Error in download.KEGG.Path(species) :
> 'species' should be one of organisms listed in 'http://www.genome.jp/kegg/catalog/org_list.html'....

I have tried all the methods that can be found on the internet, and I even re-installed the package `clusterProfiler` via Bioconductor. But it still didn't work. And I am sure it won't be the network connection problem.

Do anyone have a feasible method that can help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Web search for that error suggests that upgrading to the latest versions of R & Bioconductor may help.